# Adding labels to a K-means cluster plot in R

Tags: r, plot

I have used some R code I found online to make a K-Means cluster plot, as follows:

```
dtmr <-DocumentTermMatrix(docs,control=list(wordLengths=c(4,15), bounds = list(global = c(50,500))))
## do tfxidf
dtm_tfxidf <- weightTfIdf(dtmr)

### k-means (this uses euclidean distance)
m <- as.matrix(dtm_tfxidf)
rownames(m) <- 1:nrow(m)

### don't forget to normalize the vectors so Euclidean makes sense
norm_eucl <- function(m) m/apply(m, MARGIN=1, FUN=function(x) sum(x^2)^.5)
m_norm <- norm_eucl(m)


### cluster into 5 clusters
cl <- kmeans(m_norm, 5)

table(cl$cluster)

### show clusters using the first 2 principal components
plot(prcomp(m_norm)$x, col=cl$cl, text(m_norm, mpg, row.names(m)))
```

This does give me  plot of the 5 clusters, I amjust wondering how can I add labels to show what each dot is?

And on a side note, is there anyway that I can see what these clusters are? The `table(cl$cluster)` line just prints five numbers, I do not know what these numbers mean, my data that I am using is just over 400 text documents.

Comment: You should include a small representative sample of data in your question to make it easier for people to replicate your desired behaviour. If nobody has responded by this evening I have some code at home that does basically exactly that using the packages ggplot and directlabels.

Answer (score 2):

The problems I can see are that the `text()` is inside the `plot` call when it should come after and that the `x` and `y` passed to `text` are not the same used to generate the plot, the result of `prcomp`.

I'm using `mtcars` as a dataset:

```
df<- mtcars

### k-means (this uses euclidean distance)
m <- as.matrix(df)
rownames(m) <- 1:nrow(m)

### don't forget to normalize the vectors so Euclidean makes sense
norm_eucl <- function(m) m/apply(m, MARGIN=1, FUN=function(x) sum(x^2)^.5)
m_norm <- norm_eucl(m)


### cluster into 5 clusters
cl <- kmeans(m_norm, 5)

table(cl$cluster)

### show clusters using the first 2 principal components

# do the PCA outside the plot function for now
PCA <-prcomp(m_norm)$x

#plot then add labels
plot(PCA, col=cl$cl)
text(x=PCA[,1], y=PCA[,2], cex=0.6, pos=4, labels=(row.names(m)))
```

[image]

For the second question, the cluster assignments are in `cl$cluster`. The `table()` call just counts how many members of each cluster there are, which is why it's reporting five numbers for you.

Comment: Thanks for this, could you explain to me what these numbers (labels) actually mean? I am very new to all of this and I don't really understand, a tutorial I was following had words for his labels, are these numbers categories that the words are put into?

Comment: Hi David, the labels are generated as per the code you provided as the `rownames` of `m`. These are defined in your code above as `rownames(m) <- 1:nrow(m)` which generates a numerical sequence from 1 to the length of `m`.  The labels can be whatever you like, for example try this `labels=(row.names(df))` to see the names of the cars.